# Динамическое построение GUI

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте! Не знаю, правильно ли я подобрал термин "динамическое построение", но суть вот в чём.

Необходимо реализовать метод, который бы через цикл выводил компоненты различных типов в определённом порядке. Скажем, сначала идут 3 JTextField (Имя, Фамилия, Отчество) - потом два JComboBox (Пол, Страна) и дальше другие текстовые поля. Метка и текстовое поле (или список) заворачиваются в JPanel. Каждой метке присваивается имя и текст. Текстовому полю или списку присваивается имя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для начала, я думаю, нужно где то сохранить имена меток и текстовых полей. А также текст меток:

```
Multimap<String, String> labels;
List<String> componentsName;
List<String> componentsList //список выводимых компонентов: "JTextField","JTextField","JComboBox" etc.. 

public void drawComponents(Multimap<String, String> labels, List<String> componentsName, List<String> componentsList ) {
            /*do something*/
        }
```

Как создать красивый цикл перебора элементов и вывести компоненты на форму?

Comment: Я так понимаю, Вы создаёте форму регистрации с пошаговой валидацией данных, или нечто подобное. Динамичные интерфейсы весьма просто и удобно создавать в JavaFX - мы просто делаем XML документ и привязываем к нему контроллер, чтобы задать поведение интерфейса. А можем и просто генерировать элементы в процессе работы программы. Но если необходимо работать с устаревающей технологией, то да, Вам понадобятся хранилище для ресурсов (Имена элементов, параметры окна и размеров элементов - можно поместить либо в конфигурационный файл, либо в конфигурационный класс с константами).

Comment: Далее, Вы просто запускаете проход через этапы регистрации: 1. Создание фрагмента формы с полями ввода. 2. Ввод данных. 3. Валидация введённых данных и возврат на пункт 2, если данные некорректные. 4. Фиксация принятых данных и переход к следующему блоку данных (пункт 1). Исполнять до тех пор пока не останется блоков для заполнения. Есть вариант - создать отдельный класс для таких форм. На входе - массив типов элементов и массив параметров для них + валидатор. На выходе - форма. Заполнили форму, передали данные валидатору. Валидно - запомнили. Вернули истину - следующий.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу вам такой вариант:

1. создайте класс описывающий этап(сократите с 3х коллекций до одной мапы). Он будет содержать поля описывающие каждый этап (имя + элемент который надо создать + можно добавить поле для результата)
2. занести в мапу номер этапа - ключ, объект этапа - значение
3. в цикле по индексу этапа вытаскивать объект из мапы,

   - инициализировать все элементы (label, JTextField ...), сделать их видимыми
   - ждать ввода от пользователя, нажатия кнопки "далее", заносить результат ввода в объект этапа
   - делать невидимыми все элементы GUI.

По итогу вы получите мапу, со всеми этапами + результатами ввода на этих этапах.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, можно попробовать просто показывать компоненты по очереди - объявляешь все, потом задаёшь размеры и свойства, а при добавлении на форму дописываешь `component.setVisible(false);` где `component` - интересующий компонент. Потом, в конце каждой проверки, если данные верны - вызываешь у всех предыдущих компонентов `component.setVisible(false)`, а у следующих - `component.setVisible(true)`